# Xbox Live Creators Program publish configuration. Publish Failed

Tags: uwp, xbox, xbox-live

I am trying to test Xbox Live on my UWP game but when I goto My Developer Dashboard and open Services -> Xbox Live and press "Test" to publish my changes to my sandbox I get the message "Publish Failed" with no additional info or explanation.

I have gone in circles with this for days and I cant work out what I'm missing. Please help. I don't know what else to write and I do hope this isn't seen as low effort If anymore info I can provided could help please let me know.

Comment: If you just only get the 'Publish Failed' message, it's hard to help u. I'm not sure if you follow the correct steps. Please follow the complete steps on [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/create-and-test-a-new-creators-title) to publish configuration to see if you still failed.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I have followed these steps exactly and I still get "Publish Failed".

Comment: Can you try creating a new project and setup the Creators Club live option again to see if this is an issue with your account or just that product?